# how to make login- logout swithces in php

Tags: php, authentication, logout

i have made registration, login, logout by using this tutorial: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

also, i tried to make log in - logout swithes and tried to have it in tophead.php of my site: www.virtucadd.com

--io tried this but it not working---

```
    <?php
        if(condition){ // is the user logged in?
           {$link = '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';   
        $welcome = $_SESSION['Username'];
        }else{ // if not logged in
            $link = '<a href="login.php">Logout</a>';
       $welcome = 'guest';
        }
        ?>

......


<li class="end"><?php echo $link; ?></li>
<li class="end"><?php echo $welcome; ?></li>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the condition you are checking?

Comment: check the if condition properly.

Comment: you have to include expected behavior and current behavior

Comment: Just as a caution, be wary of random/old tutorials you find, they often include methods that are no longer safe or are just bad ideas (`md5($password);`, `mysql_*` functions). They're ok for learning the very basics & messing around, but nothing else, certainly don't use what they suggest in a commercial site.

Comment: you should use absolute path, like ROOT_PATH/../logout.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the given tutorial url you can try something like this

```
  if($fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
    $link = '<a href="logout.php"> welcome back ['.$fgmembersite->UserFullName().'] Logout</a>';
    $link1 = '<a href="logout.php"> welcome back ['.$fgmembersite->UserFullName().'] Logout</a>';
  } else {
    $link = '<a href="login.php">Welcome guest! Login</a>';
  }
```

Comment: its working but when i navigate to another page while loggedin it shows error for. e.g index.php(i.e home page of my weburl http://virtucadd.com. it shows error[Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/virtucad/public_html/index.php:43) in /home/virtucad/public_html/include/fg_membersite.php on line 151 - See more at: http://www.virtucadd.com/index.php#sthash.ca3zxmI5.dpuf]

Comment: Hi Ram Sharma, your solution is working absolutly fine..only one more request, how can i fetch logged user name also along with logout, in above script. also if user is not logged in A Text 'Welcome guest!' along woth login option.

Comment: Hi Ram Sharma! many thanks!! above code is working absolutely fine.. can we get username and text'welcome guest' in another $link. i mean 2 $link and &link1 to be echoed in separate <li></li> . because i need these texts to be simple not with hand icon when we hover on that texts. Looking forward for your valuable reply..also can we add  text 'welcome back [username]!' text, before logout tab..?

Comment: I have added as per your requirement now you can modify `$link1` as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Check if session is set than show logout and if not than show login link...

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['session_name'])){ // is the user logged in?
   $link = '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
  }
   else
   { // if not logged in
    $link = '<a href="login.php">Login</a>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/virtucad/public_html/index.php:43) in /home/virtucad/public_html/include/fg_membersite.php on line 151 - See more at: http://www.virtucadd.com/index.php#sthash.iQp6CzVM.dpuf while navigating to other pages this error comes

Comment: Have you written anyline before "session_start();" if yes please take it down to the session_start function.. always use session on first line...

Comment: yes! i have added <?php
session_start();
?> on first line of evry page , now it is not showing above error. Thanks! only one more request, how can i fetch logged user name also along with logout, in above script. also if user is not logged in A Text 'Welcome guest!' along woth login option.

Comment: If you are saving full row in session as an array..?? than simply call $_SESSION['session_name']['username_field']; this will show the username of the logedin user... if you are just saving userID in session, than i will suggest you also create a new session that contains usersname value.. than you call that as $_SESSION['sessionname']; or simply call a new query inside session set that get the username.. these are 3 methods, use any of them.. and your required result will show..

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess, I'd say it's because you haven't fully understood how hyperlinks work - you need to give the full path to the file - e.g. http://virtucadd.com/filepath/login.php (I set the front part of my path as a global variable called $hostname, and use that to save typing out long addresses each time.)

Just putting the name of the file inside hyperlink tags won't do the trick.